# Populating Table with Values from other table if ID not in DWH table

Tags: python, mysql, database, etl, star-schema

I am performing an ETL task where I am querying tables in a Data Warehouse to see if it contains IDs in a DataFrame (df) which was created by joining tables from the operational database.

[image]

The DataFrame only has ID columns from each joined table in the operational database. I have created a variable for each of these columns, e.g. 'billing_profiles_id' as below:

```
billing_profiles_dim_id = df['billing_profiles_dim_id']
```

I am attempting to iterated row by row to see if the ID here is in the 'billing_profiles_dim' table of the Data Warehouse. Where the ID is not present, I want to populate the DWH tables row by row using the matching ID rows in the ODB:

```
for key in billing_profiles_dim_id:
    sql = "SELECT * FROM billing_profiles_dim WHERE id = '"+str(key)+"'"
    dwh_cursor.execute(sql)
    result = dwh_cursor.fetchone()
if result == None:
    sqlQuery = "SELECT * from billing_profile where id = '"+str(key)+"'"
    sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO billing_profile_dim VALUES ('"+str(key)+"','"+billing_profile.name"')
    op_cursor = op_connector.execute(sqlInsert)
    billing_profile = op_cursor.fetchone()
```

So far at least, I am receiving the following error:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

This error message points at the close of barcket at

`sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO billing_profile_dim VALUES ('"+str(key)+"','"+billing_profile.name"')`

Which I am currently unable to solve. I'm also aware that this code may run into another problem or two. Could someone please see how I can solve the current issue and please ensure that I head down the correct path?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a double tick and a +

```
sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO billing_profile_dim VALUES ('"+str(key)+"','"+billing_profile.name+"')"
```

But you should really switch to prepared statements like

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM billing_profiles_dim WHERE id = '%s'"
dwh_cursor.execute(sql,(str(key),))
...
sqlInsert = ('INSERT INTO billing_profile_dim VALUES  '
       '(%s, %s )')
dwh_cursor.execute(sqlInsert , (str(key), billing_profile.name))
```